# Multiple File Upload HTML / CSS / JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add a multiple file upload button to my application form on my website. Until now I can upload multiple files at once and a list of these files is displayed. However, I would now also like to first upload a few files and see the list and then I'd like to be able add more files and have that list stay. So far, however, the list of the already uploaded files disappears when I do that. This is the HTML, CSS as well as JS code, which I use until now. I would be happy if someone can give me tips on how to change this in the code.

I'm sorry if there are mistakes in my question. It's the first time I'm using stackoverflow and English isn't my first language.

Thanks for the help! :)

```js
updateList = function() {
      var input = document.getElementById('file');
      var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
      var children = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
          children +=  '<li>'+ input.files.item(i).name + '<span class="remove-list" onclick="return this.parentNode.remove()">X</span>' + '</li>'
      }
      output.innerHTML = children;
  }
```

```css
.custom-file {
  position: relative;
  font-family: helvetica;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;  
}

.custom-file-input{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.custom-file img{
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul.file-list{
  font-family: helvetica;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.file-list li{
  padding: 5px;
}

.remove-list{
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file" multiple onchange="javascript:updateList()" border=">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">
      <img width="30" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/54/54565.svg" /> Dateien auswählen</label>
</div>
<ul id="fileList" class="file-list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't directly change the HTML of the output, instead just use `appendChild()` to add the element to the end.

```js
updateList = function() {
      var input = document.getElementById('file');
      var output = document.getElementById('fileList');

      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = 
        `${input.files[input.files.length - 1].name}
          <span 
            class="remove-list" 
            onclick="return this.parentNode.remove()"
          >X</span>`;
      output.appendChild(li);
  }
```

```css
.custom-file {
  position: relative;
  font-family: helvetica;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;  
}

.custom-file-input{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.custom-file img{
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul.file-list{
  font-family: helvetica;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.file-list li{
  padding: 5px;
}

.remove-list{
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-file">
    <input 
      type="file" 
      class="custom-file-input" 
      id="file" 
      multiple 
      onchange="javascript:updateList()" 
      border=""
    />
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">
      <img 
        width="30" 
        src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/54/54565.svg" 
      /> 
      Dateien auswählen
    </label>
</div>
<ul id="fileList" class="file-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! 
Have a nice day :D